# How to know Intel(R) HD graphics version?

Tags: windows-7, intel-graphics

I've Intel Pentium G2030 3.00 GHz processor with Gigabyte H61M-S1 Motherboard.
I am using Windows 7 OS.

[image]

which Intel(R) HD graphics version I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just ships with Intel HD graphics, no number:
[G2030 processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/74749/Intel-Pentium-Processor-G2030-3M-Cache-3_00-GHz)

[Benchmark](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu.php?gpu=Intel%20HD%20Modded&id=3068)

Comment: I saw it, but if I know at least specs of Graphics(like speed)

Comment: Added a benchmark for you above, it roughly scores 119 points, the current highest rated card is 11.181 points.
Also battlefield for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5iN8_jgkYYo

Answer (score 2):

I like [wikipedia's "List of Intel Pentium microprocessors"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Pentium_microprocessors) for this as it lists processors by generation, and in a table so you can get a sense of how yours compares to others.

There's also [Intel Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core) to see how those compare and the CPU Architecture pages; for your G2030 see the Ivy Bridge page `<en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivy_Bridge_%28microarchitecture%29>` which gives GPU clock rate which might help some : 650MHz Normal, 1050MHz Turbo.

Also `<en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HD_and_Iris_Graphics>` is helpful; for Ivy Bridge it points to `<www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-033757.htm>` and there you can look up your processor.

Quoting Intel, for "Intel® Pentium® Processors 2000/G2000 Series with Intel® HD Graphics" :

"The product... do[es] not support the following features: Intel® Insider™ technology, Intel® InTru™ 3D Technology, and Intel® Clear Video HD Technology."

DirectX : 11.0
OpenGL : 4
OpenCL : No
Shader model support : 5
Intel® Quick Sync Video : No
Intel® Wireless Display : No